# Flutter app rejected by Apple due to advertising identifier in app category for kids

Tags: ios, flutter, facebook, idfa

My app needs to use this package [facebook_app_events](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events) in order to track app installs when promoting my app on Facebook and IG. The problem is, Apple is not allowing me to publish the app in the kinds category and shows a breach in the guidelines:

> Guideline 1.3 - Safety - Kids Category
>
> We noticed that your Kids Category app includes analytics, advertising
> and collects, transmits, or has the ability to share personal
> information or device information with third parties. Specifically:
>
> - Your app includes third-party analytics or third-party advertising with the ability to collect, transmit or share identifiable
>   information, including, for example, IDFA. We found that your app
>   references the ASIdentifierManager API, which provides access to a
>   user's IDFA, in the following location(s) in your binary:
>
> • Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit
>
> It would be appropriate to remove all instances of
> “ASIdentifierManager” from your app, even if they are not utilized in
> your app's functionality.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please remove this functionality or revise your
> app so that no personally identifiable information or device
> information is sent to third parties.

I need to keep track of my campaigns, so I can't avoid using the FB SDK. But I have no idea how to pass the review process if it's as strict as it is...any ideas?

Comment: Hi, have you tried opening an issue on the plugins [github](https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events/issues)?

Comment: I've just created one there as well https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events/issues/161

Comment: You probably have two choices; 1) Don't use any Facebook APIs or 2) Don't put your app in the "for kids" category.

Comment: Both of those are not something I'd consider if there is a 3rd option. :( It's a Kids game app, so I need to be in that category...and also, I need metrics in order to utilise marketing tools, otherwise marketing will become a endless pit of wasted money.

Comment: Apple has very strict requirements for apps in the "for kids" category.  Being able to support your marketing activities isn't one of them I'm afraid.  [You're not the only one with this problem](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/1637) - This is the issue you need to be resolved; The flutter package uses FBSDKCoreKit which is where the problem lies.